# Nginx server showing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

Lately i have been facing issue in nginx server.I couldn't figure out where the exact problem is.
**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

This is the error which i'm getting and my config is below :-

```
   server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/hp-analytics.beingatfullpotential.com/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name hp-analytics.beingatfullpotential.com www.hp-analytics.beingatfullpotential.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hp-analytics.beingatfullpotential.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hp-analytics.beingatfullpotential.com/privkey.pem;

        root /var/www/hp-analytics.beingatfullpotential.com/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name hp-analytics.beingatfullpotential.com www.hp-analytics.beingatfullpotential.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

And i have checked the error log too,couldn't find much info from there.

Comment: And what were the actions you performed just before this error?

Comment: The 500 errors are reported to the error log. There should be an access log entry showing the 500 status and a corresponding entry in the error log indicating the cause. Can you replicate the problem using `curl -I`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't remember. Could you tell me what may be the cause for this or how can i debug i have checked the error.log and access.log there is no error log

Comment: @RichardSmith I couldn't find any status in error.log/access.log .
After running the CURL command i'm getting the following response
curl -I http://hp-analytics.beingatfullpotential.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 29 May 2020 08:45:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1052
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 May 2020 10:54:22 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5ebd235e-41c"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

Comment: If the 500 status is not listed in the access log, then this is not the server that is generating it.